# loss of data when using pyspark filter select when and otherwise

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe df1 :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| null | test 1 |
| none | test 3 |
| AAAA | test 2 |
| BBBB | test 4 |
| CCCC | test 5 |

I want to keep only 3 value for column A : null, AAAA and BBBB
I did the filtrer :

```
df2= df1.select(col('*'),F.when(~col("A").isin(['AAAA','BBBB']),"null")
        .otherwise(col("A")).alias("C")
)
```

I want to have this :

| A | C | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | test 1 |
| none | null | test 3 |
| AAAA | AAAA | test 2 |
| BBBB | BBBB | test 4 |
| CCCC | null | test 5 |

but what i got is différent , I lost all the rows with value equal to AAAA :

| A | C | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | test 1 |
| none | null | test 3 |
| BBBB | BBBB | test 4 |
| CCCC | null | test 5 |

do you know what is the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: I wonder the last three rows from your result dataframe is mistyped. 
Apart from that, I run the code you gave, the output is exactly like you said, not sure what is your problem. Maybe paste more info from your output

Comment: What's your expected output? In the `select` statement you didn't filter anything, just input the values of the `C` column.

Comment: @8823, you are right about the result dataframe , I just updated the question.
theorically the result must be that but in reality no, all rows with 'AAAA' value dont show in the result dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the effective code, for filtering column `A` with values `[AAAA, BBBB]` and `NULL`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df1.withColumn('C', F.when(F.col('A').isin(['AAAA', 'BBBB']), F.col('A')).otherwise(F.lit(None)))
```

You weren't filtering the columns, but creating a new column, based on the values of `A`.

Comment: I dont mind creating a new column containing the rows with values ```AAAA``` and ```BBBB```, and the rest of the rows must contains the value "null" instead of their original value.
I run your code, it give me lesser rows than mine. all the rows with "AAAA" don't exist

Comment: In question, you asked for the filter.., anyways, what is your exact expected output?

Comment: I want to have a column C that contains ```AAAA``` if original value is AAAA, ```BBBB``` if original value is BBBB,  ```null```  for all other values. example in the question

Comment: @Ussopokingo, I have updated the code, try this out if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it gives the same result as my initial code :/

Comment: @Ussopokingo  this code is as per your latest details in the previous comment..., if you want something different, please be clear.

Comment: it exactly as I described, i know theoretically your code should work, but I dont know why it doesn't,

Comment: will it be possible for you to share your initial output?? @Ussopokingo

Comment: I edited my question, I add my initial output

Comment: problème solved, there was a problem with the source data, the pyspark filter work perfectly